# Calling of a VOID function in C

Tags: c, void

I have a small problem with a code I'm writing.
I have to use a void function to print the content of a matrix and a normal array side by side. The problem is that I have no idea how to call for the function in the MAIN function so it can be printed.

I've tried to assign it to a variable but then I get the **void value not ignored as it ought to be** . Calling for the function alone doesn't work as well. At the moment I'm clueless about how can I use a VOID function in the Main.

This is the function that I have to print.
The calling in MAIN is inside a switch case.

```
void print_all(char warehouse[][M], float price[], int n)
{
 printf("\n\n");
 int m=0, p=0;

 for (m=0; m<n; m++)
     {
      for (p=0; p<M; p++)
          {
           printf("%c TEST", warehouse[m][p]);
          }
      printf(" %.2f Euros\n", price[m]);
     }
}
```

Comment: Please don't write `main()` as `MAIN`....

Comment: just write `print_all();`

Comment: Why are you posting the implementation of a function if your question is about how to call it?

Comment: As @KarstenKoop suggested, did you try to call your function as `print_all();` ? Your print_all function looks okay, so just call it.

Comment: Using print_all(); did the trick indeed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @EOF I posted the function as well just in case there was something wrong the in function's implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main should look like this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void print_all(warehouse[][M], float price[], int n);

    int
    main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        char warehouse[][]; /* whatever your limits are in the arrays */
        float price[];

        print_all(warehouse, price, n);
        return 0;
    }
```

If you just do that and make sure you include the size of the arrays and the `n` buddy variable which always accompanies the arrays, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void print_all(char warehouse[][4],  float price[], int n)
{
 printf("\n\n");
 int m=0, p=0;
 int M = 4;

 for (m=0; m<n; m++)
     {
      for (p=0; p<M; p++)
          {
           printf("%c TEST", warehouse[m][p]);
          }
      printf(" %.2f Euros\n", price[m]);
     }
}

int main()
{

char warehouse[4][4] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '3', '4' , '1', '2', '3', '4'};
float price[4] = {23.00, 24.00, 25.00, 26.00};

/* Store values in warehouse & price. Then call it like this */ 
print_all(warehouse, price, 4);
return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
1 TEST2 TEST3 TEST4 TEST 23.00 Euros                                                                                                                                                                            
1 TEST2 TEST3 TEST4 TEST 24.00 Euros                                                                                                                                                                            
1 TEST2 TEST3 TEST4 TEST 25.00 Euros                                                                                                                                                                            
1 TEST2 TEST3 TEST4 TEST 26.00 Euros
```

Comment: what if i change  it to void * func() then how can i call this inside main function